# Use tikz macros in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Since the `axis` environment is within a `tikzpicture` I thought that you could use the usual `\draw` commands within the `axis` environment.

I am confused as to why the code below produces the red line outside of the axis?

[image]

Furthermore if you comment out just the `\addplot` call, **both** the red and blue lines are not drawn.

### Questions:

1. Why is the red line drawn outside of the axis environment?
2. Is there a way to use a `\draw` command within the `axis` environment to draw lines bwteen `axis cs` coordinates?
3. Why does commenting out the `\addplot` result in no lines being drawn?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip=false,ultra thick]
    \draw [red] (axis cs: 0.2,0.2) -- (axis cs: 0.6,0.8);
    \addplot [mark=*,blue] coordinates{( 0.2,1.2) (0.6,1.8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice that the y axis of the plot starts from 1.2 and the straight line has y coordinates from 0.2 to 0.8, so obviously it will fall outside the plot.

Comment: Wow!! How embarrassing... I guess that explains #1 and #2?  But if you comment out the `\addplot` the range of the y-axis changes such that the red line should have been drawn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As Gonzalo Medina said in his comment, the y axis in this case starts at 1.2, so a line from `0.2,0.2` to `0.6,0.8` is correctly positioned below the axis. The axis limits can only be automatically determined from `\addplot` commands, not from TikZ commands like `\draw`.
2. The way you used the `\draw` command is the correct approach to draw lines in an axis, but you have to adjust the axis limits manually if necessary (as it is in your example) by using `xmin`, `xmax`, etc.
3. If no `\addplot` commands are found in an axis, PGFplots falls back to standard axis limits and just draws the axis, but doesn't execute the `\draw` command. In this case, you should also adjust all axis limits manually. Alternatively, if you're happy with the standard axis limits (0 to 1 for x and y), you could use the `after end axis/.code` key to execute the `\draw` command.

Comment: Yep, specifying `xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1` does indeed result in the red line being drawn.  Thanks...